# Speech recognition using SetInputToWaveFile ends prematurely

Tags: c#-4.0, speech-recognition

I want to do speech recognition of an audio file.

My code is pretty basic and derived from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.setinputtowavefile.aspx). The problem is that it stops with every wave file prematurely after a few seconds even though some wave files are hours long.

How to make it scan the whole file?

```
namespace Stimmenerkennung
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //...
        Thread erkennung;
        bool completed;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            erkennung = new Thread(erkennen);
            erkennung.Start();
        }

        void erkennen()
        {
            using (SpeechRecognitionEngine recognizer =
               new SpeechRecognitionEngine())
            {

                // Create and load a grammar.
                Grammar dictation = new DictationGrammar();
                dictation.Name = "Dictation Grammar";

                recognizer.LoadGrammar(dictation);

                // Configure the input to the recognizer.
                recognizer.SetInputToWaveFile(@"REC01.wav");


                // Attach event handlers for the results of recognition.
                recognizer.SpeechRecognized +=
                  new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(recognizer_SpeechRecognized);
                recognizer.RecognizeCompleted +=
                  new EventHandler<RecognizeCompletedEventArgs>(recognizer_RecognizeCompleted);

                // Perform recognition on the entire file.
                db("Starting asynchronous recognition...");
                recognizer.RecognizeAsync();
                while (!completed)
                {
                    //fs((int)(100 / recognizer.AudioPosition.TotalSeconds * recognizer.AudioPosition.Seconds));
                    db(recognizer.AudioState.ToString());
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                }
            }
        }

        // Handle the SpeechRecognized event.
        void recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Result != null && e.Result.Text != null)
            {
                db(e.Result.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                db("  Recognized text not available.");
            }
        }

        // Handle the RecognizeCompleted event.
        void recognizer_RecognizeCompleted(object sender, RecognizeCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Cancelled)
            {
                db("  Operation cancelled.");
            }
            if (e.InputStreamEnded)
            {
                db("  End of stream encountered.");
            }
            completed = true;
        }

        void db(string t)
        {
            this.textBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine + t;
                //textBox1.Text = t;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The most basic thing wrong here is that you don't call RecognizeAsync() with the RecognizeMode.Multiple argument.

Comment: That solved it. Good work.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the file on few seconds chunks by the silences and feed the chunk to the recognizer separately. Then you can combine results into a single string.

You can use any voice activity detection implementation to perform the split, a simple energy-based VAD which calculate frame energy will be sufficient.

You can find some existing implementations of the VAD in [CMUSphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net) projet

Comment: Works with neither python nor c# as it seems. Which VAD works with c# or python?

Comment: Better yet: how to use Microsoft Speech Recognition for VAD? Goal is to have a wav-file as an input for the program to output TotalSeconds when it detects voice, better yet specify areas of voice, ie, when a block of voice starts and when it ends.